# How to import data from CSV to MySQL with quotes inside strings?

Tags: mysql, csv

Right now my csv is in this form:

> pubID, pubKey, title, year

[image: csv]

I'm using this query to load into MySQL:

```
SET NAMES utf8;
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/Users/AllanPC/Desktop/csv/Publication.csv' 
INTO TABLE publication 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
```

The problem right now is that not all of the data in csv is being loaded into mysql.

Is this problem caused by csv entry such as:

`1096, journals/acta/LescanneP12,"Backward" coninduction~ Nash equilibrium and the rationality of escation., 2012`

where the handling of the quotes "" causes some problem in the loading? How do i go about solving this issue?

Comment: Why not do a test with the double quotes out to answer the question yourself? Take the one line of the CSV file you think is causing the problem and save it as withquotes.csv. Then try to load the CSV file. For test 2, remove the double quotes and save it as withoutquotes.csv and try to load it. To solve it, you'll need to bring up the CSV file in a text editor that can handle large files (make sure you backup the original). Then, replace all double quotes with say a single quote or lead the double quote with a backslash (\")

Comment: Also, maybe even try duplicating the double quotes (i.e. """"). Tinker with it to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You defined

```
ENCLOSED BY '"'
```

inside your query, but you didn't enclose your strings inside the CSV. You will have to escape your " inside your file and enclose your strings correct with ".

I think you line should look similar to

```
1096, "journals/acta/LescanneP12","\"Backward\" coninduction~ Nash equilibrium and the rationality of escation.", 2012
```

at the end. Alternative you can try to reset the `ENCLOSED BY` to a more fitting value like empty.